# Is there an official haggadah?

Tags: history, passover-seder-hagada

Is there an official haggadah?

How does one version of a haggadah have authority over another?

Is there a most popular one, a controversial one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "version".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the minimum required sections of the Hagadah that must be said?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56333/what-are-the-minimum-required-sections-of-the-hagadah-that-must-be-said)

Comment: What is the notion of official

Comment: @kouty well, would you use a haggadah that I wrote? How do you decide which one to use?

Comment: @DoubleAA there is “the survivors haggadah”, there’s one publishedby chabad.org, there’s “sammy spiders first haggadah” etc. How do you decide which to use?

Comment: @Andrew if I publish *Romeo and Juliet* and title it "Hagada" that doesn't work for me to use it. You can use any published edition that actually contains the work "the Hagada"; it doesn't matter what it's called.

Comment: @AndrewRichmond Based on your most recent comment, you may be interested in this Q&A: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/569/how-do-you-pick-a-hagada-to-use-at-the-seder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditional editions of the [Hagada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haggadah) all share roughly the same [core text](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah?lang=bi), and many surround it with various kinds of commentary and supplementary materials. The core text itself is authorized by tradition; in that sense, I would say that any edition that includes the traditional core text is qualitatively more authoritative than one that does not. Other than that, I don't think any particular edition or commentary would claim authority over any others. They're all parallel ways of approaching the core text and experience. So many [thousands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20many%20editions%20of%20the%20hagada) of editions have been published through the ages and around the world that it would be impossible to crown one as "most popular."

Comment: It may be worth distinguishing the 'story' parts and the Halakhic procedure parts (eg. text of Kiddush blessings hallel hand-washing) which have their own external to the Haggadah existence and structure and debates. In a sense a Haggadah that lists Mayim acharonim as a step is equally authoritative (whatever that means)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Haggadah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haggadah#Authorship) is a Rabbinical text.
2. [All] Rabbinical texts (Beraytot, Mishnayos, Gemmoros, Siddur) do not have "an official version" as there was no single Rabbinical court to authorize it.

Comment: Excuse my nitpicking, but the Mishna did have an official text when it was compiled. Being transmitted orally, if course, lead to variations over the centuries. Not arguing the other examples.